# iOS : Reload a view like it's first loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, reload, viewdidload

I need to completely empty a view and when I go back over, it fully recharge.

So is it possible to totally reload a view as it's first load ; to completely empty the view for reloading it as it's first load ?

Comment: Please elaborate your question. What does your view contains and what you are trying to reload? What data you are giving to your view? Does your view contains UITableView?

There are many ways to refresh data on view based upon the components you are using in a view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible.

Remove all subviews from your super view and then add again by calling your same functions.